# Python logging caches?

Tags: python, logging

I have a function in my python package, which returns a logger:

```
import logging

def get_logger(logger_name, log_level='DEBUG') :
    """Setup and return a logger."""
    log = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
    log.setLevel(log_level)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('[%(levelname)s] %(message)s')
    handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    log.addHandler(handler)
    return log
```

I use this logger in my modules and submodules:

```
from tgtk.logger import get_logger
log = get_logger(__name__, 'DEBUG')
```

so I can use it via

```
log.debug("Debug message")
log.info("Info message")
```

etc. This worked so far perfectly, but today I encountered a weird problem: on one machine, there is no output at all. Every `log.xxx` is simply being "ignored", whatever level is set. I had some similar issues in the past and I remember that it somehow started working again after I renamed the logger, but this time it does not help.

Is there any caching or what is going on? The scripts are exactly the same (synced over SVN).

Comment: Why the formatter and stream handler on *every* logger? Why not configure the root logger, once?

Comment: Hmmm I don't know, I tried to find a way to build in a logging mechanism in my package, and this what I came up with ; )

Comment: Log messages are propagated down to the root logger, only that logger needs to be set up with a formatter and handler. See the [Python logging HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html) for more info.

Comment: Thanks, I'll reorganise that, but do you have any ideas why it's not working on one machine?

Comment: You are using a default stream handler, so it'll output to `stderr`. Are you certain that `sys.stderr` has not been redirected to `/dev/null` or similar on that machine?

Comment: I checked that with redirecting via `2> foo` but the file is empty. :-\

Comment: All that `StreamHandler` does is write to `sys.stderr`; try writing to `sys.stderr` directly and see if that actually shows up. Next up is testing if your log levels are correct.

Comment: I tried `sys.stderr.write('fooooo')` within the script and it works. How should I test the log levels?

Comment: Test with `logger.isEnabledFor(logging.DEBUG)`, vary the levels as needed.

Comment: OK this is weird, I get `False` for `log.isEnabledFor(logging.DEBUG)` although I'm setting `log.setLevel('DEBUG')`.

Comment: What is `log.manager.disable` set to?

Comment: I just found out, that `'DEBUG'` as level does not work, anymore :-\ I have to use `logging.DEBUG` instead! I guess the system was updated and this is not supported anymore?

Comment: `'DEBUG'` should still work, but it is not advisable. But if that solves your problem, then perhaps someone has misplaced a `addLevelName` call somewhere.

Comment: Yes, I have to check on that, since `'DEBUG'` definitely does not work anymore :-\ Any advise where and how to setup the root logger? Should I do it in the `__init__.py`? Since some people only import a submodule… (maybe I should ask it separately, since we're spamming the comment section)